# Split one cell into multiple rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Split single cell value into multiple rows by duplicating the id column and using only portion of the original text. Any way other than using UNION.

Here is the sample data

```
create table Spl 
(
     id INT, 
     Name VARCHAR(100)
)

insert into Spl values (1, '4334ASTBSTCST')
insert into Spl values (2, '7887ASTBSTCST')
insert into Spl values (3, '8793ASTBSTCST')
```

[image]

Comment: UNION ALL, SUBSTR etc.

Comment: Apologies, forgot to mention in the original question, looking for other approach without union all

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. What have you tried? Why have you used images for textual data?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `cross apply` with `values`:

```
select Id, v.[Name] 
from spl
cross apply (
    values
    (Left([name],7)),
    (Left([name],4) + Substring([name],8,3)),
    (Left([name],4) + Substring([name],11,3))
)v([Name])
```

Answer (score 3):

A version of cross apply

```
select Id, left([name],4) + substring([name], v.pos, v.len)
from spl
cross apply (
    values
    ( 5,3),
    ( 8,3),
    (11,3)
) v(pos,len)
```